# make variable available in other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function

```
function formSubmitListener() {
  $(".js-form").submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let input = fetchInput();
    validateInput(input);

    if (isValid) {
      serverCall()
    }
  });
}
```

`validateInput` returns a `isValid` boolean of true (if all fields on a form have been filled out) that I need to make available for the if statement. If at all possible I want to prevent the use of a global variable.

How do I make the boolean available ?

Comment: maybe: if (validateInput(input)) {...}

Comment: `return` the boolean from `validateInput()` and use that value in the `if` condition...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You didn't read correctly. I am already doing that, and the second part of your answer is my question to begin with

Comment: So if you're returning it, why aren't you using it? You clearly already know how to set a variable, as you do it in the code, so I'm not even sure what the point of the question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function formSubmitListener() {
  $(".js-form").submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let input = fetchInput();
    let isValid = validateInput(input);

    if (isValid  == true) {
      serverCall()
    }
  });
}
```

this might be what you want. set the `validateInput(input)` function call to a variable and use that variable since it will store the true/false.

or another way by putting the direct function in the if where it checks whats returned

```
function formSubmitListener() {
   $(".js-form").submit(event => {
   event.preventDefault();

   let input = fetchInput();

   if (validateInput(input)) {
  serverCall()
}
});
}
```

Comment: Great. Works. I had `if (validateInput == true)` but it did not update correctly past the first response. Why do I need to put this in a variable ?

Comment: @Helle ill edit my answer to use something like that one moment so you have two solutions

Comment: @Helle I put it as a variable because that is how we can use what was returned from validateInput(). the variable will be either true or false based on what was returned. Then for the if we can check if that variable is true.

Comment: i'll use the first one because it is cleaner. Thanks a lot (also don't know why downvoted already)

Comment: @Helle also yea I like the first way a lot, thats my preferred method. Its easier to read in my opinion and if you need to use again it is readily available

Comment: Just FYI `if (isValid)` will work and is more succinct